# Write a BYTE or Array of bytes in Ada

Tags: ada

I'm writing a simple compiler for Brainf*** in Ada, but I'm in serious trouble in the code generation, therefore I am unable to generate a binary file with opcode instructions, correctly because whenever I write the file, it saves hexa decimal value like an integer. ( Integer size )

I made a simple sample of wat I try to make:

```
With Ada, Ada.Sequential_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
Use Ada;

procedure main is

   type Byte is range -128 .. 127;
   for  Byte'Size use 16;

   package Bin_IO is new Sequential_IO(Integer);
   File      : Bin_IO.File_Type;
   FileName  : constant String := "teste.bin";
   Num       : Byte;

begin
   Bin_IO.Create(File => File,
                 Name => FileName);

   Num := 16#FF#;        
   Bin_IO.Write(File => File,
                Item => Num);

   Bin_IO.Close(File => File);
end main;
```

The spected result in file is just **FF** but, when I open the file in hex editor I have **FF00 0000**

How I can save the opcode instructions correctly correctly??

Comment: How big is the file? Are you sure the hex editor isnt just expanding out so it can show a whole world? In other words, is the file 1 byte or 4 bytes big?

Comment: Isn't it enough to change Bin_IO to `package Bin_IO is new Sequential_IO(Byte);` ?

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick that was my other thought.....

Comment: Oh, I had not realized that my mistake, not it's work, when I try to write a simple 16#F#, but, when I try to write for example 16#FF#, i got an error :( ..

Comment: That's because that seems to be out of range (-128 .. 127)

Comment: It's strange, I chenged the range to 256, and, when I write the file, I got a FF00 in Hex editor, and the spected is just FF

Comment: Defining a type called Byte, and giving it this range is slightly confusing to read. I would use another name at least.

Comment: Have a more better way to make this ?

Comment: And why is the size of Byte 16?

Comment: I tried with 16, btw, look my solution... U know if have a other good way to make then ???

Comment: Have you looked into `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO`?  `Sequential_IO` has been around since Ada 83, and while it can be used on a byte type, I suspect its original purpose was more about files of records, kind of the way COBOL programmers used to handle files in the olden days.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing line 9 to:

```
package Bin_IO is new Sequential_IO(Byte);
```

It changes the generic package to sequence of bytes.
Bin_IO.Write should now write Bytes instead.

Comment: But note that OP’s `Byte` is in fact 16 bits (`for Byte’Size use 16`).

Answer (score 0):

I found functional solution...

I changed the type to Character type, and, I just convert the machine opcode to char type and write in file, that work's very well..., I don't know if that is the best way, but works

```
With Ada, Ada.Sequential_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
Use Ada;

procedure main is

   package Bin_IO is new Sequential_IO(Character);
   File      : Bin_IO.File_Type;
   FileName  : constant String := "teste.bin";
   Num       : Character;

begin
   Bin_IO.Create(File => File,
                 Name => FileName);

   Num := Character'Val(16#97#);
   Bin_IO.Write(File => File,
                Item => Num);

   Bin_IO.Close(File => File);
end main;
```

Comment: A better alternative, I think, would be to use `Interfaces.Unsigned_8`.